# Rails - jQuery plugin issue where the function is not loaded

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use a jQuery plugin and it seems that something in the way Rails works or maybe 'jquery-rails' gem is not evaluating $.fn.

For example, if this is the plugin:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.jqzoom = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var node = this.nodeName.toLowerCase();
        if (node == 'a') {
            new jqzoom(this, options);
        }
    });
};

jqzoom = function (el, options) {
.....
}

})(jQuery);
```

After digging around I have found that even though I can call and get jqzoom in the Safai debugger, $.fn.jqzoom is simply undefined. If I paste $.fn.jqzoom = function {...} in the debugger the plugins works!

There is something in there that does not like $.fn....

Help!, please...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is jQuery.fn.jqzoom undefined? If not (i.e. it is in fact defined), it is possible that you are not mapping $ -> jQuery. If so, make sure you are loading jQuery minified source before calling $.fn.anything and you should be all set.

Comment: Yes, jQuery.fn.jqzoom is undefined. What I have found now is that if I paste all the plugin code to the debugger jQuery.fn.jqzoom will be defined. Maybe an ordering problem?

Comment: I just found that if I place a breakpoint inside the jQuery.fn.jqzoom is does not stop, but if I place a breakpoint in the parent (function ($) { function it does stops. So the file is called, but the jQuery.fn.jqzoom is not evaluated.

Comment: Well, if I include the JS in the view using javascript_include_tag it works! So why it does not work using the assets tree? Is there a way to see the load order of the assets tree?